# account defined in genesis.json has no existence when private node started using geth command

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, geth-debugging

I copied go ethereum source from heco git repository compiled and used following `genesis.json` file

```
{
    "config": {
    "chainId": 24,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "8000000", " 
  "extradata":"",
  "alloc": {
     "7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "300000" },
     "f41c74c9ae680c1aa78f42e5647a62f353b7bdde": { "balance": "400000" }
  }
}
```

then applied following two commands

```
./geth --datadir data init data/genesis.json
```

and

```
./geth  --networkid 24 --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 console
```

but when I checks balance of above mentioned account using the command below on geth console

```
eth.getBalance("0x7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82")
```

it shows `undefined` means this account has no existance and no balance, so is my genesis block does not taking effect or I am missing any step, please explain my mistake and proper solution for it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out as there was a need to put `--datadir' again while starting node and there must be write permission on that data folder to respective user who is starting the node